# Invisible ReCaptcha for Subscribe Button

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have a simple newsletter signup on the bottom of a website([www.valleygolfwillmar.com](http://www.valleygolfwillmar.com)). I've been getting a lot of spam bot email addresses so decided to add Invisible ReCaptcha to help cut down on non-user submitions.

Everything seems to be working fine, email address get added to the .TXT file, except when you click subscribe it opens the php script that is used to write the txt file that saves all the email addresses.

Before recaptcha was added it would just have a little pop up message saying "Subscribed! Thank you!".  How can i make this work again with invisible ReCaptcha?

Here is the Newsletter code:

```
<!-- Newsletter Form -->
<h4 class="letter-spacing-1">Join Our Newsletter</h4>
    <p>Subscribe to Our Newsletter to get info on Upcoming Events &amp; Offers</p>

    <form  id="newsletter" class="validate" action="php/newsletter.php" 
           method="post" data-success="Subscribed! Thank you!" 
           data-toastr-position="bottom-right">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" 
                   class="form-control required" placeholder="Enter your Email">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success g-recaptcha" 
                        data-badge="inline" 
                        data-sitekey="6LdIn1gUAAAAAB7ds1fYb2awLLPBKz1Z5d4qm23e" 
                        data-callback="onSubmit" type="submit">Subscribe
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>

    <style>
        .grecaptcha-badge {display: none;}
    </style>

    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script>
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("newsletter").submit();
        }
    </script>
<!-- /Newsletter Form -->
```

Here is the PHP code for the newsletter I have been using:

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     v1.0.0
 * @author      
 * @date        Saturday, April 9, 2016
**/ 
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
@ini_set('track_errors', 0);

$array['email'] = isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? ckmail($_REQUEST['email']) : false;

if($array['email'] !== false) {

    $fh = fopen('_newsletter.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n" . $array['email']);
    fclose($fh);

    unset($fh, $array);
}

/************************************ 
 @CHECK EMAIL
/************************************/
function ckmail($email) {
    $email = trim(strtolower($email));
    if(preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/',trim($email))){
        return $email;
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not part of the question but your regex for the email will block potential subscribers with valid emails. Building a regex that will allow all possible variations is true nightmare. There is a built in function in php 5+ http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php . Don't know how well (for both blocking and allowing) that works as I don't use it. I generally think, that all browsers since 10-15 years back has auto fill to complete forms so why would they even need to type the email?

Comment: I don't understand what that means, I'm not familiar with regex.  The list has been working great collection emails for me for the past few years, I just get a lot of fake spam emails submitted, that why i want to add recaptcha

Comment: A recaptcha doesn't stop a user from submitting a fake email, there is no way to check if an email is fake or not (by CODE), you'll have to send a verification email to your users to check if they actually own the email.

Comment: I know, I'm not worried about people submitting fakes, it's the spam bots I want to stop.  This is a golf course in a small town with really low website traffic, I don't mind the occasional person submitting a fake. It's the robots I want to stop, or at least cut back on

Comment: @DanGraves If you look at this list http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt all these are valid TLDs. That means a person can have an email `john.james.doe@somedomain.americanfamily` and that is a valid email. Your regex will not allow his tripple names nor the americanfamily TLD. About your actual question, why not just add a echo with the message?